# jQuery click outside tag

Tags: jquery

I have html, for example

```
<body><div id="main"><p>some text</p></div></div></div></body>
```

How to make on jquery when you click outside #main, but inside tag body some action?

```
$(":not(#main)").click({..});
```

don't working

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this:

```
    $("body").children().filter(":not(#main)").click(function(){...});
```

Comment: That's so much better (cleaner and more concise) than my own suggestion...+1! =)

Comment: Also can write in one line $("body>:not(#main)").click(function(){...});

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').click(function(e){
  //if click inside #main
  if($(e.target).parents('#main').length || $(e.target).is('#main')){
  ...
  }
  else{
    //if not clicked inside #main
  }

})
```

check here http://jsfiddle.net/gwams/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like:

```
$('body').click(
    function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is('#main') || $(e.target).closest('#main').length){
            // main was clicked
        }
        else {
            // something else was clicked
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rptGa/).

Answer (score 0):

First you should change the Html to:

```
<body><div id="main"><p>some text</p></div></body>
```

It has two unclosed div tags, And then David's answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id != 'main') {
        console.log('outside main but within body');
    } else {
        console.log('within main');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').click(function () {
   alert('clicked');
});

$('#main').click(function (event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Should stop clicks inside `#main` to propagate down to `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("body>:not(#main)").click(function(){...});`

Modified from samn

If you need the live version just change to

`$("body>:not(#main)").live("click", function(){...});`